# Is there a free editable client-side grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I presently have a read-only view of some tabular data in an HTML page. I would now like to create an editable view of it.

Is there any easy-to-use client-side component written in JavaScript that I can use to quickly create an editable table that will allow me to add new rows, save them, and edit existing rows?

I've used KendoUI and DevExpress controls in the past, both, their server side and client side controls. But they are paid.

Also, I am not sure if jQuery UI presents such a control.

Comment: have you seen [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: We are not here to do research for people. Do it yourself!

Comment: Was going to recommend datatables editor but I saw you asked for something free :-) I've been working with it on a project, a little quirky but if you don't need too much customization it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatables, here's simple inline editing:
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: Thank you. It looks nice. Is there documentation available on how to use it with .NET on the server side?

Comment: Okay, I just saw the .NET libraries section on their website. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Although datatables.net is free. Editor is not free

Answer (score 1):

If u need a inline edit in a table, better go for [Data Table](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple). It has many inbuilt features.

Comment: Thank you. I just looked at it. Is there some documentation available on how to use it with .NET on the server side? I see that they have provided only PHP libraries for server-side use.

Comment: Okay, I just saw the .NET libraries section on their website. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I could have voted your answer also as the correct but I just gave it to @Lamar because I noticed he has a lesser score. :-) Hope you will understand. This is not the first time I wish we could vote more than one answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SlickGrid .

---

> https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

---

It provides Support for **editing** and **creating new rows**.

See editable Example : http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html

Comment: Thank you, pawan. It looks useful but it looks like I'll have to spend plenty of time learning it whereas the DataTables component suggested above has lots of documentation that I think will be easier for me to use now. :-)

Comment: Data Table is also a very good lib with lots of features . I am happy you got what you wanted :)